# Issues while integrating Mapbox Vision and Navigation SDK in a Single Application using Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: mapbox

I want to Integrate Mapbox Navigation and Vision SDK's in a Single Project. But I'm getting duplicate classes error while building an application. If i try to exclude the module: 'mapbox-android-core' in build.gradle file as mentioned below :

```
`implementation "com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision-safety:0.13.0", {
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-core'
}`
```

then its creating  another issue:

`E/MapboxTelemetry: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mapbox/android/core/MapboxSdkInfoForUserAgentGenerator; E/libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::PendingJavaException A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 22560 (Thread-3), pid 22319 (e.ar_navigation)`

I want to Integrate Mapbox Navigation, Vision an Search SDK in a Single Project with out creating duplicate classes error.

How actually my build.gradle is :
// Maps Navigation dependencies

```
implementation "com.mapbox.navigation:ui-dropin:2.11.0"
implementation "com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.11.0"

implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.42.6", 
  {
  exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-core'
  }

//Search SDK integration
  implementation ("com.mapbox.search:autofill:1.0.0-beta.45")
  implementation ("com.mapbox.search:discover:1.0.0-beta.45")
  implementation ("com.mapbox.search:offline:1.0.0-beta.45")
  implementation ("com.mapbox.search:mapbox-search-android:1.0.0-beta.45")
  implementation ("com.mapbox.search:mapbox-search-android-ui:1.0.0-beta.45")
// Vision SDk Integration

 implementation "com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision:0.13.0", {
   exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-core'
  }
 implementation "com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision-ar:0.13.0", {
   exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-core'
 }
implementation "com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision-safety:0.13.0", 
{
 exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-core'
}
```